# How can I disable automatically joining the General chat when I log in?

Tags: diablo-iii

This is stupid. I don't want to chat with other people. How can I disable auto-chat-join?

Comment: [Everything is *stupid*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkmhFLIZJVI&t=8m52s)

Comment: This question is going Platinum...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After significant investigation, the only option right now is to leave the channel when you log in, to do this type

> /leave

Leaving the channel will persist in [patch 1.03](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5639242748#1).

> Please note that we will also be making a change with patch 1.0.3 so that if you leave General chat once, the game will remember this preference and you will not automatically join General chat again when logging in. While we don't yet have a date to share for this patch, we anticipate that it will be released before the end of the month.

Comment: I really hope they leave it in as an option in the social menu, at least until they fix the 3007 errors. I disconnect roughly ever 5-10 minutes unless I'm in general chat, and forgetting to join every time I login is frustrating.

Comment: I don't know why they didn't make it an option in the first place.  Sure, make it default to "on", but what nincompoop decided "hey, let's throw everyone in general chat, and shove them back in it when they restart the game, even if they'd left the channel before!" ?

Really, I'd like to see a more refined chat interface similar to WoW's, where you can create separate tabs and set up filters (so you can have a tab for whispers, a tab for party, and then a tab for one or more public channels).  Additionally, WoW remembers what channels you were/weren't in when you restart.

Comment: @MrSmooth, what? You can prevent disconnection by being in the chat?

Comment: @JuanManuel Yeah being in general chat fixes 3007 errors. Don't think it fixes any others though. You'll know if yours are 3007 errors just from the fact that you can't play for more than 10 minutes at a time without being disconnected.

Comment: Leaving the channel already persists.

Comment: @Oak Actually, I think they just turned off auto-joining entirely.  The "opt-in" auto-join is still slated for patch 1.03.

Comment: @oak bwarner is correct. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5639242748#1

Answer (score 4):

This does not exist yet, but [Blizzard has stated that they plan on adding it in a future patch](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5592452657#4):

> We're looking to add functionality in a future patch that will "remember" if you've left General chat. It'll work similarly to World of Warcraft -- after you've left General chat once, you won't be automatically re-added to the channel whenever you next log in. It will essentially "opt you out" of the channel, but you'll still be able to re-join it manually.

In the meantime, you will have to use /leave each time you join in (but not before reporting all the gold-selling spammers first, right?).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a way to automatically not join, but you can either click on the uppermost icon next to the chat area (looks like a gear, titled Public Chat Options) and select "Leave Channel" or type /leave.

Answer (score -1):

`/home The Void` Sets your default Channel to a closed/muted one.