# Can I turn off chat auto-join?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable automatically joining the General chat when I log in?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71069/how-can-i-disable-automatically-joining-the-general-chat-when-i-log-in)

With this week's patch, I'm now being automatically entered into public chat when I first log in.  The amount of signal-to-noise in public chat is far too low for me to enjoy.  I've tried finding a setting to disable auto-join, but can't find it.  Am I blind, or do I have to manually leave chat every time I start Diablo 3?