# How can I leave General chat?

Tags: the-secret-world

I typed `/help` and read every command, and came across the `/chat` command. According to the info, `/chat leave General` should make me leave the channel, but it doesn't. How can I leave the General chat (but still have access to the other rooms, like LookingForGroup)?

Comment: [So antisocial](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71069/how-can-i-disable-automatically-joining-the-general-chat-when-i-log-in)

Comment: General chat in TSW is worse than D3 in that there are guilds(Cabals) spamming constantly for members :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to turn off the subscription to General chat.

On your chat frame, you'll see several tabs, such as '**General**', '**Combat**' and '**Tell Messages**'.

You can right click on these to change the channels and information feeds that each tab is 'Subscribed' to. You'll need to do this on every login for now, but a fix is supposedly 'coming soon'.